# Can the Arduino Uno use a negative supply voltage (0V & -5V)

Tags: arduino-uno, voltage-level

I acquired a bread-making machine. See control board image.
I want to use the machine for other purposes and control the buttons, paddle, heater & 7-segment display with an Uno.
As it stands, the machine provides 0V, -5V & -11V to the control board.

Is it possible to connect 0V to Uno VIN and -5V to Uno GND pins?

My initial idea was to replace the PENTALPHA-BV30K with an Uno and mapping the pins accordingly. I couldn't find any datasheet for the BV30K, however I'm reverse engineering the control board anyway.

Control board findings:

- -11V is used to drive the A/B/C/D/E/F/G/DP segments of the LED display
- BV30K only uses 0V & -5V

[image: bread machine control board]

I added an image of the transformer based power supply board so that I could check the supply there. The larger heatsink is for the 7905 IC and the smaller heatsink is for the BTA06 Triac.

[image]

Comment: *"0V, -5V & -11V"* How do you know your meter probes aren't just swapped?

Comment: Voltages measured with Black (COM) meter probe connected to 0V & Red meter probe connected to -5V  & -11V on the larger white header on the control board. The header is also labelled as such.

Comment: I saw the - on the header silkscreen. It looks just as easily like a poor choice of punctuation. This is part of why I asked. Is there an ground plane in this thing? Is there a place that strapped the metal parts are strapped together that cross checks as showing -5 when you put your positive probe on the thing that says "5V" or "-5V" depending on how you look at it. If there isn't scarcely makes a difference if your UNO is running in the same system, because -5 to 0 is still 5V. The UNO doesn't much care what you label ground as long as whatever it's talking to agrees with it.

Comment: I ask mostly because it may just be a matter of perception and there's much of a question here. I wouldn't expect -5V and -11V in that thing unless maybe it's from the 70s and I guess, for that time, very high end.

Comment: I originally thought  that the "dash" was just bad punctuation.
I then started to reverse engineer the control board circuit. Those switching transistors are A1015, PNP. The emitter (in most) is strapped to (what is labelled) 0V. The collector is strapped, through a resistor, to (-)5V. The base is connected, through a resistor to a control pin on the IC BV30K. That's when I realised it must be negative 5V, relative to 0V. Otherwise the switching circuit would not work.
When testing with a meter there does not appear to be a connection between the metal earthed chassis and 0V on the board.

Comment: !! CAUTION !! ... the bread maker board may have powerline voltage on it, relative to earth ground

Comment: I'm not really sure what would make decent answer to this. What can be said about the Arduino in this context is just true of electronics generally. That circuits, independent of any other concern, care what what voltage difference is applied across them. The UNO is not somehow an exemption to this. So if you have any two voltage numbers that are 5V different, say -7805 VDC and -7800 VDC (to pick something absurd) you can put them in the right order to make a 5V "positive" difference. The thing is I get the sense from your comments you're at least that far along in your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I normally would have just tried it after satisfying my own doubts - I just didn't want to cremate the Uno just yet. Anyway, I connected 0V to Uno VIN and -5V to Uno GND pins and all is well ;) I guess I'll put "yes" as the answer but really not sure why it was designed with the negative supply.

Comment: Has this device got a transformer in its power supply to isolate it from the mains voltage? If not, then it will be using some sort of transfomer-less power supply which will probably not be able to supply much more current to drive the Uno and any connections to that board risk bringing mains voltages outside. If in doubt, use optocouplers for any connections and a separate power supply for the Uno. Optocouplers would anyway make the +5v / -5v issue irrelevant.

Comment: How far have you reverse engineered the circuit now? What is the -11V good for? As long as all pins of the BV30K are in the 0V to -5V range, I would go on.

Comment: @6v6gt It's a transformer power supply - see updated images. I notice there's an optoisolator there too.

Comment: @thebusybee The -11V is used to drive the A/B/C/D/E/F/G/DP segments of the LED display. The BV30K only uses 0V & -5V.

Comment: The image of the power supply board suggests that there is no separation between powerline and the low-voltage parts. **Make sure to protect yourself.** However, you can connect the Uno directly. Just prohibit connections to PCs or humans during operation. -- BTW, please add requested information to the question. Down here in the comments other visitors will not read it. ;-)

Comment: @thebusybee - Added info to the question. I'm interested in what you said about the powerline separation. There is a large air gap on the underside, there is a transformer and there is an optoisolator, which I haven't looked at yet but will do. Granted, the separation **could** be better. Once finished the boards will be housed exactly as they were before in the bread machine, separated by about 15cm and a metal plate. Interaction with humans will be the only way the machine will work ;) The make/model is a Ronson 9110. This may be sliding off-topic a bit but it all helps build a good answer.

Comment: @thebusybee - Also, I was thinking that I could use the -11V supply instead of the -5V supply and connect the USB to program in situ, overriding the USB power supply. Thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

As you describe the system, you can connect the system's ground to 5V of the Uno, and the system's -5V to Uno's ground.

Please note that you cannot reverse-feed 5V through the pin with the same label, it is an output. You can use the USB connector. You might want to solder wires at its pins instead of cannibalizing an old USB cable. Alternatively you can try VIN, as there is a LDO, but measure the resulting voltage. The specification demands at least 7V there.

If you want to power the Uno during development by the USB connection, you can disconnect any of -5V or ground, but not both, because you need a reference connection.

In contrast, you cannot use the -11V supply and use VIN and GND of the Uno, because the Uno's voltage regulator uses the lower level as reference and will set Uno's "high" (5V) to about -6V with reference to the system's ground. See:

[image]

---

Concerning the separation of power-line and the controller: Well, I'm just worrying about your health.

If you are sure that all is done well, go ahead. With a working separation you can even dare to connect the development PC to your Uno while the power-line is connected.